# How to send an email containing information of two tables side by side in Excel (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, email

I am struggling to send two separate table information in one email.
I have already coded the programme to set the range but I would like to send the email in a way that the two range (tables) are displayed **side by side** when recipient receives it.

This is the current my code.

```
.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(thismonth) & RangetoHTML(nextmonth)
```

It displays all the information but just not in a side by side arrangement, currently it is displaying in vertical way. Is there a way to send them side by side?? I am still very new to VBA any help is appreciated!

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Option one (easiest):

Use VBA to arrange you data in Excel in the desired layout, then use that Excel layout to send in an email.

Option two (requires HTML skills):

create the HTML code that shows the two tables side by side, nested in a layout table. This will require HTML code to create a layout table with one row and two columns and place the *thismonth* and the *nextmonth* tables inside these HTML table cells. You will need an understanding of how HTML works.

Edit: sample table code

```
<table> 
   <tr> 
      <td>table 1 code with all the html</td>
      <td>table 2 code with all the html</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Option three:

Just concatenating two tables with an ampersand will never fly when you use HTMLBody, unless you serve it with the CSS required to float one table side by side the other table. Feeding CSS into an email is way more complex than the two approaches above.

Comment: is there any way I can implement this?<table align="left">
    <tr>
        <td>table 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>table 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>

Comment: No, you need to nest the two tables into the cells of an outer table. I have edited my answer with some sample code.